# Is there a function in tkinter to cycle through windows

Tags: python, tkinter

I Just started writing GUI programs and i want to have a window that pops up a certain amount of times currently i have a button and an entry box and the buttons command is on_press shown below

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack()

        self.button_bonus = tk.Button(self, text="go", command=self.on_press)
        self.button_bonus.pack()


    def on_press(self):
        for i in range(int(self.entry.get())):
            self.popup()


    def popup(self):
        win = tk.Toplevel()
        win.wm_title("Window")

        l = tk.Label(win, text="Input")
        l.grid(row=0, column=0)

        b = tk.Button(win, text="Okay", command=win.destroy)
        b.grid(row=1, column=0)

root = tk.Tk()

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

The expected behavior is i press the button the loop will call popup() once then wait until the popup is closed before letting another window spawn.but what i have currently both windows spawn at once

what i have now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `win.grab_set()` and `win.wait_window()` to make the popup a modal window:

```
def popup(self):
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.wm_title("Window")

    l = tk.Label(win, text="Input")
    l.grid(row=0, column=0)

    b = tk.Button(win, text="Okay", command=win.destroy)
    b.grid(row=1, column=0)

    win.grab_set() # capture keyboard events
    win.wait_window() # wait until window is closed
```